# How to create an Azure DTAP street

Tags: azure, msdn

We're making our first steps to Azure with a commercial website. The first steps of programming are taken and all works perfect. But now we want to create an DTAP (Development, testing, acceptance and production) environment for this website for maintenance and support. The website is at this stage not yet deployed.

For development purposes we use an MSDN subscription and a dev/test environment. The point is that you should not run an commercial website on your msdn account (for SLA reasons), so we should deploy it to an production azure environment. So our goal is to create a DTAP street where the DTAP environments are an exact match.

How do we accomplish that? I mean can we (easily) cascade the "DT" environment from our MSDN account to an acceptance/production environment and thus a different Azure account? (Like the staging slots within a single production environment). Is that possible?

Comment: Do you have answered this question already?